# Alinear radio button

Tags: html, bootstrap

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Sexo</span>
    <span class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="style-0a2">
        <span> Right</span> 
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="style-0a2">
        <span> Left</span> 
      </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Necesito que quede con el mismo color de fondo que tiene el span "sexo" , en formato input
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo similar a esto pero sin el input text y con los radio button del mismo lado y todo el input del mismo color plateado gracias saludos !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías describir un poco _más_ cual es el problema y el objetivo? (Edita tu pregunta para añadir más información)

Comment: Estás usando algún css?

Comment: Estoy usando Bootstrap v3.2

Answer (score 4):

Pon `sexo` en medio y edita un poco el estilo del `.input-group` para darle un color de fondo, un borde, un redondeado en las eaquinas y un padding a los lados. Al label `sexo` que está en medio, dale un margin a los lados para separarlo de los radios.

**Ejemplo**

```css
#sexo {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#sexo label {
  display: inline-block;
}
#sexo label:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group" id="sexo">
    <span class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="style-0a2">
        <span> Right</span> 
      </label>
      <label>Sexo</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="radiobox" name="style-0a2">
        <span> Left</span> 
      </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto podría servirte:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio"> Right
      </label>
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio"> Left
      </label>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Pordrías detallar un poco más tu respuesta? Así como está no entiendo qué quieres decir.

Comment: ¡Editado! Perdona, es que había puesto dos espacios en lugar de cuatro...